# Modelling Top Surface

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling a bottle shape. And when I add the subdivision modifier the top and rear of the bottle has its surface seem pinched non smooth (although I have added shade smooth). So I delete the top face, select the vertices and do a grid fill which can be seen in the image attached. But when I increase the viewport quality in my subdivision modifier the top of the bottle seems more square than circle.

What's the best modelling tip so the top of the surface doesnt make that pinched surface?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to *isolate* areas of topology where the interpolation of normals (used by smooth shading) might screw the illusion of a smooth surface from parts of the model where it matters - from places where curvature has to be kept even.

Either:

- <kbd>I</kbd> inset the flat top region, and
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut a loop around the neck and slide it
  up towards the rim

Or:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel the rim with (e.g.) 2 Segments and
  a Profile of 1,which has the same effect.

Now the thin triangular faces are in a flat area, all have the same normals, so no interpolation

Or....

... you could do the bevel with a Bevel modifier, targeted by angle .. or edge Bevel Weight, so you can adjust the bevel later.. you could split the normals for shading alone without adding any geometry or subdivision, by going to the Data tab and checking 'Autosmooth' .. or..